# How to make unit test fail when API of mocked module changed

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking

When I write some javascript unit tests for my code, I mocked a methond of a module with sinon, defined what arguments it expected and what it should return.

someone changed the argument of that method and he forgot to change my code. now my code were broken, but the unit tests still passed because I used the mocked module in the unit tests.

how to make unit tests fail when mocked module changed, so that this issue could be exposed?

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can do this with JS (or another duck-typed, un-checked language).

Comment: isn't it the way unit tests should work? isn't what you want to achieve should be done in integration tests? (i'm new to testing)

Comment: @llamerr Thanks! we have not wrote enough integration tests for this new project. so I want to know if there any way to exposed this kind of issue before commit code.

Comment: I'd love to have a way to do this, but I think only Flow or Typescript can do the verification you want. Otherwise, you have to rely on your integration tests.